# replacing values from two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a small issue that I hope you'll be able to help me with :) I've tried to provide simplified examples to help you see what I mean. I'm using python 2.6.

So, I'm currently trying to re-assign some values in a file which represents interactions between two objects. The interaction file (file1) looks something like this:

```
Thing1  Thing2  0.625
Thing2  Thing3  0.191
Thing1  Thing3  0.173
```

Whilst my other file (file2), also a `tsv`, looks something like:

```
DiffName1  Thing1  ...
DiffName2  Thing2  ...
DiffName3  Thing3  ...
```

Essentially, I'd like to take `file1`, find the corresponding `'DiffName'` value in file2, and make a new file with the same layout as file1 but with 'Thing1' replaced with 'DiffName1' and so on, whilst maintaining the structure of `file1`. i.e two columns with corresponding interaction value.

So far, from asking questions and reading answers on here, I've achieved similar results with this script: (I've checked but there may be some redundant/wrong things in here)

```
import csv
import sys

interaction_file = sys.argv[1]
Out_file = sys.argv[2]
f_output = open(Out_file, 'wb')

ids = {}            

with open('file2') as f_file2:  
    csv_file2 = csv.reader(f_file2, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_file2)

    for cols in csv_file2:
        ids[cols[7]] = cols[0] 

with open(interaction_file, 'rb') as f_file1:       
    csv_file1 = csv.reader(f_file1, delimiter='\t')     
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')   

    for cols in csv_file1:              
        csv_output.writerow([ids.get(cols[0], cols[0]), ids.get(cols[1], cols[1]), cols[2]])
```

But for whatever reason, I suspect due to the slightly different layout of `file2` compared to the file that this scripts was originally written for, I've been unable to make this work for me. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to understand each line of this file but I still can't quite get it running, possibly because I don't quite fully understand the final line:

```
csv_output.writerow([ids.get(cols[0], cols[0]), ids.get(cols[1], cols[1]), cols[2]])
```

Is anyone able to give me some advice?

Cheers,

Matthew

Comment: Do you have the freedom to use Pandas? If so, please try it using pandas join or str.replace functions,

Comment: How exactly is it not working for you?

Comment: I was just enquiring, if you have the freedom to use Pandas.

Comment: Unfortunately my scripts are largely run on servers where I don't have root access so I would prefer to not use pandas

Answer (score 0):

Is in that line `ids[cols[7]] = cols[0]` just a typo, you seem to have only 2 columns in your example, and you are trying to use 7th column.

What it does, is that you declare a dictionary and populate it from 2nd file. Then, when you search in dictionary with get `ids.get(cols[0], cols[0])`, it will search for a key `cols[0]` and if it is not in dictionary, it will return second argument of get function, in this case `cols[0]` itself.

Comment: Yes, this a typo, my apologies. It's left from when I had a similar task but wanted to take the value at position 7 of my file2 and change it to be at position 1 of the dictionary. At least that's my understanding of that line.

Answer (score 0):

I added some annotations to your script and changed/shortened some bits. The [docs on `dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) should help you understand the last line:

```
import csv, sys

interaction_file, out_file = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
f_output = open(out_file, 'wb')          

with open('file2') as f_file2:
    # get lines as list and slice off header row
    rows = list(csv.reader(f_file2, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='\t'))[1:]  

    # ids: Thing* as key, DiffName* as value
    ids = {row[1]: row[0] for row in rows}

with open(interaction_file, 'rb') as f_file1:       
    csv_file1 = csv.reader(f_file1, delimiter='\t')     
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')   

    for row in csv_file1:   
        csv_output.writerow([ids.get(row[0], row[0]), ids.get(row[1], row[1]), row[2]])
        # ids.get(row[0], row[0]): dict.get(key[, default])
        # use value (DiffName*) for key row[0] (Thing*) from ids,
        # or use row[0] (Thing*) itself
        # if it is not present as a key in ids
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your comments certainly helped me understand a little better.

However, this script doesn't change my file whatsoever. I've changed around the index position in the final line to try and understand what's going wrong, but nothing is affecting the output. (output looks the same as interaction file)

Comment: Well, you should put some debugging `print` statements in there to see what the actual rows, keys, and values are that are being processed. Otherwise it is difficult to diagnose from afar ;)

Comment: `for row in rows:
  ids = {row[1]: row[0]}
  print ids`

produces a dictionary which represents `Name: DiffName` as expected. What I don't understand is how come if I change the index positions in the last line, how come that's not represented in my output.

Comment: What is the output of `print row` in the very last loop?

Comment: It prints exact copies of the lines in my input file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your input files have correct delimiters. And also seeing the error message would be good.